# Running 2 instances of mysql, one local 3306 and one for ampps?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, ampps

I have a local mysql server running on port 3306, and installed ampps that uses mysql, what i need is to be able to run the mysql instance from ampps and have the local mysql at the same time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really need two instances? Seems a bit of a waste of resources? Can you you just use one instance for all your databases? Why the need for separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: On ampps, change my.conf port to a different one, for example 3307, restart mysql (on ampps interface) and you are good to go!